# How can I add a non-escaped string as a plaintext node or as an attribute value?

Tags: go, goquery

I am trying to use a string containing a ' character as an attribute value. However, ' is always replaced with &#39;. Is there a way around this? Since the value is enclosed with ", ' wouldn't necessarily have to be escaped, would it? The same happens when I try to add a plain text html node.

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

var htmlString = `<div class="catch-me-if-you-can">‍♂️</div>`

func main() {
    qHtml, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(strings.NewReader(htmlString))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    n := &html.Node{
        Type: html.ElementNode,
        Data: "zombie-hunter",
        Attr: []html.Attribute{
            {Key: "meta", Val: "{name: 'RedEye!', equipment: 'Baseball Bat'}"},
        },
    }

    qHtml.Find(`div`).First().ReplaceWithNodes(n)

    goquery.Render(os.Stdout, qHtml.Contents())
}
```

Output:

```html
<html><head></head><body><zombie-hunter meta="{name: &#39;RedEye!&#39;, equipment: &#39;Baseball Bat&#39;}"></zombie-hunter></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not (easily) possible as `goquery` relies on `golang.org/x/net/html.Render()` for HTML output and that [hardcodes](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/net/+/master:html/render.go;drc=4f7140c49acb4c7e276e0b67dea953d5344ae064;l=74) text-node [escaping](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/net/+/master:html/escape.go;drc=3d87fd621ca9a824c5cff17216ce44769456cb3f;l=208).

```golang
// no goquery involved here...
func main() {
    w := new(strings.Builder)
    n := &html.Node{
        Type: html.ElementNode,
        Data: "zombie-hunter",
        Attr: []html.Attribute{
            {Key: "meta", Val: "{name: 'RedEye!', equipment: 'Baseball Bat'}"},
        },
    }
    html.Render(w, n)
    fmt.Println(w.String())
}
```

```
<zombie-hunter meta="{name: &#39;RedEye!&#39;, equipment: &#39;Baseball Bat&#39;}"></zombie-hunter>
```

If you really need it you'd probably need to re-implement `html.Render()` (and related functions) to not escape this one character and patch `goquery` to use your implementation then. Given `&#39;` is valid HTML escape and will render same as ' in browser I'd not recommend doing that.

Comment: Like I wrote in my question, I had the same problem when I tried to add a simple text node. I found out you could set "Type: html.RawNode". That got around the problem for this simple example.